# pi-type bonding interaction along the bond

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

I was given the diagram of $\ce{BF3}$'s LUMO and asked to assess its bonding character as shown below:

[image: Unannotated BF3 HOMO LUMO]

Below is the model answer for the annotated version.

I managed to correctly answer the HOMO MO with the same annotations but was confused here slightly.

The LUMO Interaction shows a $\ce{p}$ orbital coming out of the plane, where the B p orbital is out of phase with the $\ce{F3}$ fragmnet orbitals, but the model answer suggests there is a $\ce{\pi}$ type bonding interaction.

This does not make sense to me. 
Unless mistaken, I thought the p-orbitals from the B and the F atoms (given they are out of phase) show along the bond $\ce{\pi}$ type *antibonding* properties, rather than $\ce{\pi}$-type bonding interaction.

[image: BF3 HOMO LUMO annotated]

Am I correct or not? How is there $\ce{pi}$-type bonding interaction possible along the bond here?